# get the end date base from the given start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

Im using [moment js](http://momentjs.com/) and what I want is get the calculated month, year and day from the specified start month, day and year within a year e.g. if Jan 1, 2015 is the start date then it should be Dec 31, 2015, any ideas, clues, suggestion, how to do it?

Below is 2 input fields that has an identity id of 'startdate' and 'enddate'

```
<input type="text" id="startdate" value="Jan 1, 2015" />
<input type="text" id="enddate" />
```

so if user pick from a datepicker from an input field that has an id of 'startdate' then (assume i used datepicker that output a format of MMM,DD,YYYY) the input field that has an id of 'enddate' should contains the end date (month, days, year) base from the started date within the current year of the start date (assume Jan 1, 2015, then end date is Dec, 31, 2015).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startdate").change(function(){
        $("#enddate").val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [endof](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) like this:

```
var endDate = moment(startDate).endOf('year');
```

However if you are looking to add 1 years to the start date then you can try this:

```
var endDate = moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add('days', 365).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Comment: how about base from the given year? like if February then the end year should be January of the next year since the calculation is 1 year.

Comment: @CodeDemon:- I think I am missing something? You want to get the month after 1 years? I mean for 1 Feb 2014 the end date should be 31 Jan 2016? or you wan to add 1 year to the current date?

Comment: no. I want to get the month, days, year within 12 months of the given start date e.g. if give date is Jan 1, 2015 then the end date is Dec 31, 2015

Comment: @CodeDemon:- What would be the enddate for 1 Feb 2014?

Comment: the end date of feb 1, 2014 is January 2015 since it will be calculated on its 12 months from the start date.

Comment: this works "moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add('days', 365);" but how can i use it if the start date format is e.g. Oct 15, 2015 and I want only to get the month, day, year of the end date and no other stuff, the end date output is like this "Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800" so it kind of missed up. any ideas?

Comment: @CodeDemon:- You need to add `.format("DD/MM/YYYY")` Update my answer.

Comment: @CodeDemon:- You can specify other [formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) as well like `.format('MM-YYYY');`

Comment: so can i use the format of ".format("YYYY DD,MM")  since my start date format is ("Jan 1, 2015)?

Comment: @CodeDemon:- Yes you can. You can use `.format('MMM DD, YYYY');` http://jsfiddle.net/PAc3j/120/